# Verify input on change in dynamic list Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Based on a drop down that has a value in the 1-10 range I am displaying N Rows (N = value of dropdown)

Each row acts as an object because it has 3 properties: x,y,z. All the rows I generate are stored in an array so the final format of the data is:

```
data:{
    rows: [
        {x:0,y:0,z:value},
        .......
        ]
    }
```

I have to verify that for each row the value of x,y,z doesn't pass 100 and if it does display an error.

I've tried doing it with a function that parses the array on each input change but besides the fact that it seem very inefficient it sometimes doesn't work.

How can I handle this validation on dynamically generated inputs ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your request but this code, https://codepen.io/zerbene/pen/XWKWMoP,  might interest you. It is about filtering an array of objects to display them using computed

Answer (score 0):

Make a watcher that observes the array changes :

```
data:{
    rows: [
        {x:0,y:0,z:value},
        .......
        ]
    },
watch:{
  rows:{
        handler(val){
         let check=this.rows.every(row=>Object.values(row).every(v=>v<100))
          if(!check){
             //error
          }
       },
     deep:true
  }
}
```

Comment: This has the same usage when rows is inside another object called FORM ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean